# Prestashop: Custom module not showing in back-office

Tags: prestashop

I want to create a custom module in prestashop but it does not show up in the modules-tab in the back-office.

I created a very basic test-module but even this does not show up in back-office.

I have a single text.php file in the folder: modules/test
This is the code of the file:

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class Test extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  

        $this->name = 'Test';
        $this->tab = 'Test';
        $this->version = 1.0;
        $this->author = 'Test';
        $this->need_instance = 0;

        $this->displayName = 'TEST';
        $this->description = 'TEST';
    }

    public function install()
    {
        return (parent::install());
    }
}
```

As far as I understand this is enough for a basic module to show up in the back-offices's modules tab.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Try to rename your text.php to test.php

Answer (score 2):

In your test module there can be a few reasons of that:

1. you need to have you name your file the same as folder so it would be test.php in modules/test folder
2. $this->name = 'test'; test should be lower-case as stated in [Prestashop official guide](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module#CreatingaPrestaShopmodule-Modulesfolder) 
   'name' attribute. Serves as an internal identifier, so make it unique, without special characters or spaces, and keep it lower-case.

Answer (score 0):

Note the location of parent::__construct();

I think you are calling the parent before setting enough information. I would also suggest using a different name for your test module, something less generic.

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class Test extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->name = 'Test';
        $this->tab = 'Test';
        $this->version = 1.0;
        $this->author = 'Test';
        $this->need_instance = 0;

        parent::__construct();  

        $this->displayName = 'TEST';
        $this->description = 'TEST';
    }

    public function install()
    {
        return (parent::install());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of PS are you using? If < 1.5, seems that a stable and less bugged 1.4.10 was released few days ago.
I am using 1.4.10 at my website Panapaná (http://www.panapana.com.br) and faced a similar problem when I was using 1.4.8.2. After migration to 1.4.10, this problem no longer exists.